# Navigation controller and status bar issue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

I'm struggling to manage the status bar since I placed a Navigation Controller.
When my intro navigation flow passes only through ViewControllers it worked smoothly.
Now I put a Navigation controller in front of my introVC and the frame is shifted down by the size of the status bar as shown in the images linked below.

Now how it looks like :

[image: after]

I cannot understand how to solve it, can you please give me some advice?

Here my Storybord :

[image: Storyboard]

Michele

Comment: do you post your storyBoard screenshot?

Comment: Hi Joe, I add my Storyboard screen. Thank you

Comment: your screenshot looks like you haven't embedded naviationController properly and its not very clear to understand. can you post your whole storyBoard? and make sure navigationController `barVisibility` ticked on  `Shows navigation Bar` in  `Attribute Inspector` ?

Comment: pls select navigation viewcontroller  and select check mark box "Bar Visibility" as selected

Comment: Hi, I dont need a Navigation Bar, so I disabled all barVisibility checkbox.

Comment: My Storyboard includes more then 30 VC and a screenshot of all my storyboard is not readable. My impression is that the NC embed my VC down the status bar, but my VC includes also the height of the status bar (self.view.frame.height) so there is a small vertical scroll effect now..

Comment: @MicheleA. you need to adjust your view constraints to manage it .

Answer (score 0):

Have you embed your introVC into a Navigation controller or how did you connect those two?

Comment: Hi Misha, I create a NC and selected my VC as root VC.

Comment: I used a segue ctrl+drag link. Thank you

Comment: I don't know if it may help you, but select the VC that you want to embed in the NavBarController, and select Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller ... I had the same problem once and managed it to fix it through that

Comment: @Misha your answer more look likes a comment.